# SQL gives me one result in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hi can anyone help me with my problem, im currently working with my query where i want to display a users from the difference date. but there is a lot of duplicating users so i decided to use a group by sql. but the output is only 1 data. here is my sql:

```
SELECT
                    c.col_id,
                    c.col_quantity,
                    c.col_request_date,
                    c.col_status,
                    u.col_name,
                    u.col_lname,
                    u.col_phone,
                    u.col_address,
                    p.col_name,
                    p.col_supplier,
                    p.col_quantity,
                    p.col_price,
                    p.col_image
                FROM 
                    tbl_cart AS c 
                JOIN 
                    tbl_users AS u 
                ON 
                    u.col_acct_id = c.col_user_id 
                JOIN 
                    tbl_product AS p 
                ON 
                    p.col_id = c.col_product_id 
                WHERE 
                    (c.col_status = "checkout" OR c.col_status = "checkout_complete") 
                GROUP BY 
                    (c.col_user_id AND c.col_request_date)
```

Comment: there's no php here or pdo for that matter.

Comment: wdym? @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: I don't know what "wdym" means. Best guess: "what do you mean"? if that is so, then write it out as that.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: use comma in group by, not AND.

Comment: what I mean is that you say you're not getting results from "php". You tagged the question as such *and* pdo, but there's not supported code.

Comment: what does https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php throw you back, given a pdo connection of course.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner oh sorry, i think i put a wrong tag

Comment: @rlanvin thanks it works

Comment: change group by to be comma not and

Comment: i already did it, @connormcwood thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `GROUP BY` does what you really need, but you are aggregating by a boolean expression.

Try this:

```
GROUP BY c.col_user_id, c.col_request_date
```

The `AND` produces one of three values:  true, false, `NULL`.  In this case, it is probably always evaluating to true, because neither value is every `NULL` or zero.  Hence, you are only getting one row.

This is an example of why you *never* want to use the MySQL (mis)feature that allows unaggregated keys in the `SELECT`, unless you really know what you are doing.  I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of how you want to choose one record or another from among the many records with the same user and request date.